# how to efficiently deep clone an array of objects with an arraylist as a field

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, clone, deep-copy

deepest element:

```
class Player {
    //fields contain:
    int value;
}
```

collected in:

```
class Team {
    //fields contain:
    ArrayList<Player> players;
}
```

collected in:

```
class Splitter {
    //fields contain:
    Teams[] teams;
}
```

In a function in `Splitter` I have to clone `teams`. I basically have to clone the array `teams` by cloning each `Team` object, which each contains an ArrayList `players` I have to clone. I *do not* want to clone the Player objects themselves.

My solution thus far looks something like this:

```
private Team[] deepClone(Team[] teams) {
    Team[] new_teams = new Team[teams.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
        new_teams[i] = new Team();
        for (Player player : teams[i].getPlayers())
            new_teams[i].getPlayers().add(player);
    }
    return new_teams;
}
```

anything I could change to make this more efficient or elegant?

Comment: Honestly, this does not look ugly! You're a prefectionistah ;-)

Comment: do you have java-8?

Comment: `.getPlayers().addAll(teams[i].getPlayers())` can save you nested `for`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current solution is equivalent to this simpler form:

```
private Team[] deepClone(Team[] teams) {
    Team[] new_teams = new Team[teams.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
        new_teams[i] = new Team();
        new_teams[i].getPlayers().addAll(teams[i].getPlayers());
    }
    return new_teams;
}
```

You can make this more elegant without the loop indexes using streams and lambdas:

```
private Team[] deepClone(Team[] teams) {
    return Stream.of(teams).map(team -> {
        Team newTeam = new Team();
        return newTeam.getPlayers().addAll(team.getPlayers());
    }).toArray(Team[]::new);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ideally you should clone Players also if you wanna do perfect deep cloning , we should always write clone method in each class and just call that clone method to get clone, anyways you can go in below way .

```
class Team {
        //fields contain:
        ArrayList<Player> players;
        public Team clone() {
           Team team = new Team();
           team.players.addAll(players);
           return team;
        }
    }

// ...

    Team[] deepCloneTeams(Team[] teams) {
        Team[] newTeams = new Team[teams.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < teams.length; i++)
            newTeams[i] = teams[i].clone();
        return newTeams;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you're not technically cloning players, you're using the same reference of players.
You should have some method that instances a new player and copies the (immutable) values of player and clones the mutable object attributes of player if you want to actually (deep) clone them.

Something along the lines of:

```
class Player{
    // your attributes and methods
    Player getClone(){
        Player p = new Player();
        // set all immutable attributes and clone all mutable attribute objects
        return p;
    }
}

class Team {
    //fields contain:
    ArrayList<Player> players;
    public Team clone() {
        Team team = new Team();
        team.players.addAll(players.stream().forEach(p->p.getClone()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return team;
    }
}
```

There's a nice example here https://howtodoinjava.com/java/collections/arraylist/arraylist-clone-deep-copy/